# Populate Kendo UI StockChart with Model object

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz, jstockchart

Below is my code snippets , everything seems to be good to go even in my controller data in "data" variable is correct which means list of 51 elements . but when i run the code it throws the exception mentioned below

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TelerikMvcApp1.Models.StockDataPoint]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'TelerikMvcApp1.Models.StockDataPoint'.

I know this exception is due to Usage of List , but why not and what is the solution

**Model:**

```
public class StockChart
{
    public List<StockDataPoint> responseData()
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string url = "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/StockData";

        string EncryptedJson = client.DownloadString(url);

        string resultString_01 =  EncryptedJson.Substring(9, EncryptedJson.Length - 9); //remove the callback( from the jsonp
        string resultString_02 = resultString_01.Remove(resultString_01.Length - 1); //remove the ) from the same previous response string

        List<StockDataPoint> stockData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<StockDataPoint>>(resultString_02); // convert the json string to json response


            return stockData;
    }


}

public class StockDataPoint
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public decimal Close { get; set; }

    public long Volume { get; set; }

    public decimal Open { get; set; }

    public decimal High { get; set; }

    public decimal Low { get; set; }

    public string Symbol { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var stock = new StockChart();
            List<StockDataPoint> data = stock.responseData();
            return View(data);
        }
```

**View:**

```
@model TelerikMvcApp1.Models.StockDataPoint
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="chart-wrapper">
    @(Html.Kendo().StockChart<TelerikMvcApp1.Models.StockDataPoint>()
        .Name("stockChart")
        .Title("The Boeing Company (NYSE:BA)")
        .DataSource(ds => ds.Read(read => read
            .Action("Index", "Home")
        ))
        .DateField("Date")
        .Panes(panes =>
        {
            panes.Add().Title("Value");
            panes.Add("volumePane").Title("Volume").Height(150);
        })
        .CategoryAxis(axis => axis.Pane("volumePane"))
        .ValueAxis(axis => axis.Numeric().Line(line => line.Visible(false)))
        .ValueAxis(axis => axis.Numeric("volumeAxis").Pane("volumePane").Visible(false))
        .Series(series =>
        {
            series.Candlestick(s => s.Open, s => s.High, s => s.Low, s => s.Close);
            series.Column(s => s.Volume).Axis("volumeAxis")
                    .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip.Format("{0:C0}"));
        })
        .Navigator(nav => nav
            .Series(series =>
            {
                series.Area(s => s.Close);
            })
            .Select(
                DateTime.Parse("2009/02/05"),
                DateTime.Parse("2011/10/07")
            )
        )
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:600px;" })
    )
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all you dont need this code at all in your View `@model TelerikMvcApp1.Models.StockDataPoint` since kendo will automatically ask your controller to provide data for the Chart in this part of code:

```
     DataSource(ds => ds.Read(read => read
                .Action("_BoeingStockData", "Financial") // first arg is the method name, 
//second one is the controller name without Controller postfix (Financial is for the FinancialController)
```

So the second thing , you need to write _BoeingStockData method, as example you could use this one:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult _BoeingStockData()
{
    var db = new SampleEntities();

    return Json(
        from s in db.Stocks
        where s.Symbol == "BA"
        select new StockDataPoint
        {
            Date = s.Date,
            Open = s.Open,
            High = s.High,
            Low = s.Low,
            Close = s.Close,
            Volume = s.Volume
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: all you did is copy paste from Kendo.Mvc.Examples files but dear you can see that i'm not using db in my model . i'm getting data from API

Comment: You are getting data form "api" yes, but where is your own _BoeingStockData method? To solve your initial problem you need to chage `@model TelerikMvcApp1.Models.StockDataPoint` to `List<@model TelerikMvcApp1.Models.StockDataPoint>`

Comment: sorry to bother you but i've already updated my question and changed the name of controller and action

Comment: SampleEntities(); you mentioned is something which is not in  my project

Comment: You can change `SmapleEntities()` to smth like this `var stock = new StockChart();
            List<StockDataPoint> data = stock.responseData(); `

Comment: @funkyCataz kindly have a look on my code i have that snippet already